# Single-dimensional arrays as equivalents of multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array defined as follows:

```
Tile[,] Tiles
```

It contains 100 elements in the X axis, and 150 elements in the Y axis. This differs from map to map in my game though, but I always know the amount of tiles in the X and the Y axis.

Given this, how can I convert the above array to a single-dimensional array, and iterate through them? I know that single-dimensional arrays are 2 times faster than multi-dimensional arrays, and that means a lot to the performance of my game. Furthermore, single dimensional arrays can be used with parallel computing.

Comment: I doubt your application performance will degrade from using a two-dimensional array:) With using a one-dimensional array, you will just make your code harder to read and maintain...

Comment: I would like to know the source for "single-dimensional arrays are 2 times faster than multi-dimensional arrays". And the source for your implication that multi-dimensional arrays cannot be used in parallel computing. It would be nice to know how you're using the array to optimize for specific scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if items count on Y axis is fixed for every X, you can try this.
Assume a = *count on X axis*  and b = *count on Y axis*;
you can define `Tiles = new Tile[a*b];`
Then `Tiles[x,y]` becomes `Tiles[x*b+y]`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to know the size of 2d array here suppose :- (2x3)

```
//xPosition and yPosition are the index of 2D array (1,2)
int xPosition = 1;
int yPosition = 2;
```

3 is ySize of 2d array.

```
int OneDArrayIndex = (3*xPosition)+ yPosition ;
```

This will give the index for 1D array and you can insert your value at this index in OneD array.

Hope this helps.....

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static int[] TwoDArrayToOneDArray( int[][] TwoDArray, int xSize, int ySize)
        {
            int xIndex = 0;
            int OneDArrayIndex = 0;
            int[] oneDArray = new int[xSize * ySize];
            for (int yIndex = 0; yIndex < ySize && xIndex < xSize; yIndex++)
            {

                OneDArrayIndex = (ySize * xIndex) + yIndex;
                oneDArray[OneDArrayIndex] = TwoDArray[xIndex][yIndex];
                if (yIndex == ySize - 1)
                {
                    yIndex = 0;
                    xIndex = xIndex++;
                }
            }
            return oneDArray;
        }
```